# Advice with strange NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Here is my class. I have a problem. I fill all data correctly and when I'm making `Toast` i've got `NullPointerExeption`. I don't know why. I'm making all inputs in `EditTexts`.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Wyslij extends Activity {

    protected final int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 30;
    EditText et_nazwa;
    EditText et_nip;
    EditText et_adres;
    ImageButton ib_wyslij;


    final TowarZamowienie tz = new TowarZamowienie();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wyslij);

        et_nazwa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_nazwa);
        et_nip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_nip);
        et_adres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_adres);
        ib_wyslij = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_wyslij);

        String nazwa_firmy = et_nazwa.getText().toString();
        String nip_firmowy = et_nip.getText().toString();
        String adres_firmy = et_adres.getText().toString();

        final Zamowienie zam = new Zamowienie();

        if (nazwa_firmy != null && !nazwa_firmy.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            zam.klient.setNazwa(et_nazwa.getText().toString());
        }

        if (nip_firmowy != null && !nip_firmowy.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            zam.klient.setNip(et_nip.getText().toString());
        }

        if (adres_firmy != null && !adres_firmy.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            zam.klient.setAdres(et_adres.getText().toString());
        }

        final String suma_zamowienia = podaj_sume(TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione);

        zam.setSuma(suma_zamowienia);

        zam.setZam_id(MainActivity.nr_zamowienia);

        MainActivity.nr_zamowienia++;

        tz.setZam_id(zam.getZam_id());

        final String[] s = new String[TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione.size(); i++) {

            s[i] = TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione.get(i).getTows_id();
        }

        ib_wyslij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // new

                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        zam.klient.getNazwa()+ " "+zam.klient.getNip()+" "+zam.klient.getAdres().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });

    }



    private String podaj_sume(ArrayList<Towar> l) {
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            suma += l.get(i).Tow_ilosc * l.get(i).Tow_cena;
        }

        return String.valueOf(suma);
    }

}
```

My LogCat errors:

> 02-11 23:08:59.546: W/dalvikvm(17234): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40be71f8)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at com.example.inzynierka.Wyslij$1.onClick(Wyslij.java:110)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14152)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>   02-11 23:08:59.554: E/AndroidRuntime(17234):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Zamowienie.class
public class Zamowienie {

```
public int id;

public int zam_id;

public String suma;


public Klient klient;

public Zamowienie(int id, String suma, Klient klient) {
    super();
    this.zam_id = id;
    this.suma = suma;
    this.klient = klient;
}
public Zamowienie() {
    super();
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public int getZam_id() {
    return zam_id;
}
public void setZam_id(int zam_id) {
    this.zam_id = zam_id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getSuma() {
    return suma;
}
public void setSuma(String suma) {
    this.suma = suma;
}
```

}

Comment: please post the logcat and indicate in which line the NPE happens.

Comment: @Henry done, anything else ?

Comment: Yes, which line is `Wyslij.java:110`?

Comment: `zam.klient.getNazwa()""` This doesn't even compile..

Comment: Note that debugging might help finding what's null on :110

Comment: @Henry
This is line 110:
Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        zam.klient.getNazwa()+" "+zam.klient.getNip()+" "+zam.klient.getAdres().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

Comment: @RC. upper is line 110

Comment: Please post code for `Zamowienie`

Comment: My guess would be that either `zam.klient` or `zam.klient.getAdres()` is `null`. Do you set `zam.klient` in the constructor of `Zamowienie`?

Comment: @JStevenPerry here it is

Comment: @Henry here is my Zamownienie.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate()` you do this:

```
final Zamowienie zam = new Zamowienie();
```

and then you try to access `zam.klient`

but you never set `zam.klient` to anything, so it is null.

Comment: Mr Wasser, you're the best ! Thanks A LOT ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting this in OnClick:

```
Toast.makeText(Wyslij.this,
                        zam.klient.getNazwa()+ " "+zam.klient.getNip()+" "+zam.klient.getAdres().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the `klient` variable of class `Zamownienie`. The variable is not set. You are calling the no-arg constructor of `Zamownienie` which means `klient` is set to `null`.

Please consider using standard Java naming conventions as well as NOT giving class variables `public` scope.

HTH